# Нагрузочные тесты на Selenium

Tags: selenium, нагрузочное-тестирование

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, документацию с базовыми примерами, как сделать нагрузочный тест на Selenium, какие связки при этом использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Вынужден Вас расстроить. Selenium не используется для нагрузочных тестов т.к. что бы эмулировать 1000 пользователей придется запустить 1000 браузеров, а это очень большие ресурсы.